# Bayesian Nash Equilibria in Battle of Sexes

Tags: game-theory, bayesian-game

Consider the static Bayesian game as described below. $\ t_1$ and  $\ _2$[image] are the types of the row and column player respectively, which are both uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. The first part of the question is asking us to find a Bayesian Nash Equilibrium. Trivially, don't the the top left and bottom right corners correspond to equilibrium outcomes? Unless I've misunderstood the definition of a BNE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. All types $t_{1}$ choose O (B) and all types $t_{2}$
choose O (B) are both Bayesian equilibria.

Note that there are other Bayesian equilibrium in this game, if you are interested this is explained in detail [here](https://users.auth.gr/kehagiat/Research/GameTheory/02Courses/Course3/06-incomplete-info.pdf) (p. 10, see reference below) for this particular battle of the sexes with two-sided incomplete information. The basic idea is to note that in this game, each player has a continuum of types, and so the set of types is infinite. You can look for a Bayesian equilibrium in which player 1 goes to the $Opera$ if $t_{1}$ exceeds some critical value $x_{1}$ and chooses $Fight$ otherwise, and player 2 chooses to $Fight$ if $t_{2}$ exceeds some critical value $x_{2}$ and goes to the $Opera$ otherwise. To find the values $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ that make these strategies a Bayesian equilibrium you can calculate each player's expected payoffs given the other player's strategy and find the optimal values based on this.

*Game Theory: Static and Dynamic Games of Incomplete Information
Branislav L. Slantchev Department of Political Science, University of California – San Diego*

Comment: Ideally you would post a short description of the linked content, because links break over time. You can give a name that people can google, quote, etc.

Comment: Fantastic. I must point out that the question had a hint about threshold values which is what confused me. Perhaps that is covered in your link.

Comment: I have modified it to include the idea and reference @Giskard, thanks for the tip

Comment: @Student yes, there is a Bayesian equilibrium with threshold values. I included a quick hint here but it is very well explained in the link.

Comment: Being new to Bayesian games, it seems like methods for solving such games (including auctions) rely on us assuming some form for the strategies and then proceeding (an example is the threshold equilibrium in the above game). Would there be any exhaustive methods for solving Bayesian games?

Comment: Well I am not sure what you mean by assuming some form of the strategies, as the set is fixed by the very game setup. The essential idea that you want to ask yourself, as with any Nash equilibrium, is in what situation will neither of the players (in this case 2) have a profitable deviation? So obviously the most straight forward answer is, as you pointed out, the situation in which {Opera, Opera} and {Fight, Fight}. However, rational choice implies that you take into account the strategy of the other player given a priori knowledge of the probability of his type [...]

Comment: so for some value of the types (affecting payoffs) the expected payoff of a certain action is higher than for the remaining possible strategies, giving you an equilibrium. Exhaustive methods for solving Bayesian games thus essentially involve considering all possibilities. At times this is not an easy task (at least speaking from my own exposure) but in my humble opinion it really boils down to considering every possible scenario.

Comment: Another consideration of course is whether you are being asked to find A Bayesian equilibrium or all of them. Either way, remembering how you play in pure strategies with complete information (i.e. player 1 plays opera and player 2 plays opera) coupled with the calculation of the expected value given the a priori probabilities given incomplete information is a good rule of thumb to find such equilibria.

Comment: Thanks, I essentially meant assuming things such as symmetry, monotonicity etc, which is common in the auction games I've encountered. Monotonicity is sometimes necessary for an equilibrium strategy, but symmetry is not. So such methods are not comprehensive, is what I meant.

Comment: Properties like monotonicity, symmetry etc maybe useful depending on context. These aren't general rules for finding out BNEs. And in problems like auctions, optimizing over arbitrary function spaces may be incredibly tough. So people look for simple properties - say linear functions and solve for it (and then show that such properties would hold in eqm). Another example: Cheap Talk. You'll see everyone solving for partitional equilibrium. And they're very easy to solve. Crawford Sobel, in fact, showed that any eqm of  their cheap talk games would have a partitional form!